# GAE Python - Saving database query into cookie

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I am trying to save a database query into a cookie since I require the result on every page. When hard-coding an expiry-date into the code everything works fine, but when I replace the hard-coded date by a dynamic "next day" expiry, it is giving me the following error:

```
self.response.headers.add_header(str('Set-Cookie'), str('shops=%s; path=/; expires=%s') % shoplist expire_string)
                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried to use the response.set_cookie method but this didn't work at all, which is why I decided to go with the code below:

```
class CookieHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        shoplist = Shop.all().filter('active = ', True).order('abbrev')
        expire_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        expire_string = expire_date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
        self.response.headers.add_header(str('Set-Cookie'), str('shops=%s; path=/; expires=%s') % shoplist expire_string)
```

**UPDATE**
To give some more information about the content - it is a query of all shopnames in a database. The query is used for an autocomplete functionality on a searchbox that is visible on every page.

Comment: You do realize that somebody could just modify the cookie and gain complete control over your Db, right?

Comment: really? the results are just used to fill an autocomplete functionality which then has to re-query the database anyway. I wasn't aware that there was such a risk there. How would this work?

Comment: What would be the best practice for not having the browser query the database each time a new page loads?

Comment: I don't think there's a security issue here. @RohanPrabhu probably just read "saving query into cookie" and assumed you meant saving the query itself, (not its results) and then later having your server execute whatever query is in the cookie.

Comment: The code as shown is saving the query itself, and not the results.

Comment: Yes the code didn't really work as it should. Some more research revealed that memcache actually does exactly what I want but on server-side, which is even better and easier to implement. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is happening because the "%" operator expects a tuple to its right, so your line of code should be:

```
self.response.headers.add_header(str('Set-Cookie'), str('shops=%s; path=/; expires=%s') % (shoplist, expire_string))
```

Note the extra parentheses and comma.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, it solved the error! Now all I have to do is figure out if this is actually the best way of doing this..

Comment: @Vincent You could just have a list of shop names at a separate URL, (in JSON, say) and then set a large expiry time in the response headers for that URL. The browser will fetch it the first time and then likely not again until that expiry.